# Use manually created id instead of system id in if block

Tags: android, contextmenu

**TLDR:**

I'd rather use 'shareButton' intead of '2131427332' when referring to the item clicked that brings up `onCreateContextMenu()`. How can I do this?

**Explanation:**

I have an activity with two context menus.  So, in my `onCreateContextMenu()` method, I'm retrieving the id of the item clicked, and inflating the corresponding menu.

But - the only way I know how to do that is using the `v.getId();` - which seems bad/strange since I'm using a system-generated id in my if block instead of an id I created myself.  Is there a better way to do this?  Will that id ever change?  Can I use the id of the XML item instead of this auto-generated id?

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Opens the context menu(s)
 */
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(v.getId() == 2131427332)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == 2131427329)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use yours ids referencing autogenerated R.class

for example:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.my_custom_id) 
{

}
```

as I remember some time ago the ids in R.class was static final, but google team changed it to just static so now you can't use them in switch statement but feel free to use them in your code.

Found it! More about that here: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: I think my minSdkVersion 8 makes it so I can only use integers in switch statements right?

Comment: @Dave Both switch and if will work and it has nothing to do with the API level. There is only an issue with library projects: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: @brillenheini - awesome ty - changed it to a switch statement and working great!

Answer (score 0):

So you have a view that is called shareButton.

What you have to do is to replace this:

```
if(v.getId() == 2131427332) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    }
```

with this:

```
if(v.equals(shareButton)) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    }
```

Simple as that!